# Someone Accidentally Made Unity and Top Bar too big. Help!

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Someone was on my computer and messed with the size of unity launcher and the little bar (I forgot what it's called) on top of stuff. Since the stuff is too big, I can get to the part of settings to fix it. Is there a way to fix it. I'm on 14.04

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings - Appearance - Look and in the bottom-right corner is a slider for changing the Launcher icon size. Drag the marker either direction to increase or decrease the icon size on the Unity launcher.

[image]

Look here for details : [How-to-geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/188096/how-to-resize-the-unity-launcher-icons-in-ubuntu-14.04/)

Comment: And if you can't see the slider, move the window around, by holding `Alt` and dragging with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the resolution and the scale from menu and title bars.

System Settings, display.

[image]

...if you can't see the whole window and you can't drag it, use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to drag it. Just hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and try draging the window from anywhere with the mouse.